# Cross product direction in Spherical coordiantes

Tags: geometry, multivariable-calculus, spherical-coordinates, cross-product

[image]

The cross product of a vector $\vec{m}$ with $\hat{r}$ gives $m\sin\theta \hat{\phi}$ as claimed by the author.

This would probably be trivial but a lot of these subtle technicalities were not encountered in my first year multivariate course. This is slowing down my progression considerably in Physics.

I want to know how $\hat{\phi}$ is determined.

Edit:

I'd like to add that the direction due to the above cross product must be perpendicular to both $\vec{m}$ and $\hat{r}$. Clearly, It must lie on the xy-plane for it to be mutually perpendicular to $\vec{m}$ and $\hat{r}$. But the $\phi$ is elusive.

Comment: Hint: use a $\LaTeX$ symbol `\sin` for sine function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let the unit vectors in spherical coordinates be $\hat{\rho},\hat{\theta},\hat{\phi}$.

Note that $\vec{m}=m \hat{z}$, that $\hat{z}=\cos\theta \hat{\rho}-\sin\theta \hat{\theta}$ and that $\hat{\theta}\times\hat{\rho}=-\hat{\phi}$.

So the cross-product is $$\vec{m}\times \hat{\rho}=m(\cos\theta \hat{\rho}-\sin\theta \hat{\theta})\times\hat{\rho}=m\sin\theta \hat{\phi}.$$

Comment: @Mathematicing Did this answer your question? Otherwise, please do let me know.

Comment: Can you give me a detailed cross product workings?

Comment: Is $\rho$=1? or is it a linear combination of some basis?

Comment: Yes, the length $\rho$ is 1, as it is a unit vector. What part of the cross-product workings is causing you trouble? Remember that cross-products are distributive, i.e., if $a,b,c$ are 3D vectors, then $a\times(b+c)=a\times b+a \times c.$

Comment: @Mathematicing Also note that $\rho$ *is* a basis vector.

Comment: Actually, I got it. I was over thinking it. Thanks for the assistance.

Comment: @Mathematicing No problem :)

Answer (score 1):

Compare the spherical coordinates and Cartesian coordinates:
$$\vec{n}(r, \varphi, \theta) = \begin{cases}
x = r \cos(\varphi) \sin(\theta) \\
y = r \sin(\varphi) \sin(\theta) \\
z = r \cos(\theta) \end{cases}$$

[By definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spherical_coordinate_system#Integration_and_differentiation_in_spherical_coordinates), the spherical coordinate system unit vectors are
$$\hat{r} = \begin{cases}
x = \cos(\varphi) \sin(\theta) \\
y = \sin(\varphi) \sin(\theta) \\
z = \cos(\theta) \end{cases}, \; \hat{\varphi} = \begin{cases}
x = -\sin(\varphi) \\
y = \cos(\varphi) \\
z = 0 \end{cases}, \; \hat{\theta} = \begin{cases}
x = \cos(\varphi) \cos(\theta) \\
y = \sin(\varphi) \cos(\theta) \\
z = -\sin(\theta) \end{cases}$$

If
$$\vec{m} = \begin{cases} x = 0 \\ y = 0 \\ z = m \end{cases}$$
then $\vec{m} \times \hat{r}$ in Cartesian coordinates is
$$\vec{m} \times \hat{r} = \begin{cases}
x = -m \sin(\varphi) \sin(\theta) \\
y =  m \cos(\varphi) \sin(\theta) \\
z = 0 \end{cases}$$
and $m \sin(\theta) \hat{\varphi}$ is
$$m \sin(\theta) \hat{\varphi} = \begin{cases}
x = -m \sin(\theta) \sin(\varphi) \\
y =  m \sin(\theta) \cos(\varphi) \\
z = 0 \end{cases}$$
The two are obviously equal.